# PHP version update gone wrong

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, php

I've followed [instructions](http://www.dev-metal.com/how-to-setup-latest-version-of-php-5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) on updating the PHP version on my server from 5.3 to 5.5

During the installation it threw php5-common dependency errors.
I've managed to fix the dependency errors by completely whipping the current apache version and php, and installed them from scratch.

Now I'm getting this error:

```
* Starting web server apache2
*
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 55 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

The line in question contains the following:

```
#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
# 
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
```

Commenting out the line follows up with another error: (missing httpd.conf file)

```
* Starting web server apache2
*
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 214 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Creating an empty `httpd.conf` file produces yet another error:

```
* Starting web server apache2
*
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 43 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf:
SSLSessionCache: 'shmcb' session cache not supported (known names: ). Maybe you need to load the appropriate socache module (mod_socache_shmcb?).
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Please help me with this. My boss is a bit of a cheap-a## and skimped on a system technician.
 So keep in mind that you're talking to a PHP developer with extremely limited knowledge of Linux\Unix systems.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/368515/upgraded-to-ubuntu-13-10-apache-not-able-to-start](http://askubuntu.com/questions/368515/upgraded-to-ubuntu-13-10-apache-not-able-to-start) but please remember to **save a backup copy** of configs and other files you are changing.