# Unable to start Apache2 with Error AH00526: Syntax error - Invalid command $

Tags: 14.04, apache2, reinstall

Recently I re-installed Apache because of some problem but since then this particular error is failing it to start.

[image: Invalid command $.]

There are related answers which I have tried like below but that too not effective:

[Upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 - Apache not able to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368515/upgraded-to-ubuntu-13-10-apache-not-able-to-start/368542#368542)

My Apache configuration file line 222 is as below:

```
    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
    $ Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Will be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: Post the content of line 222 `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf'` in your question.

Comment: Can you also include apache error log?

Comment: @Achu It is giving a blank apache error log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `$`, that's all.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Navigate to line 222 and use a `#` as comment or remove the `$` if you need the configuration in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`.

Comment: removing $ showed some more error. Then I tried putting # in the beginning which worked. Appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to obvious to me: the error complains about a $. There is a $ in the config file ad you copied it.

That $ does not belong in the config file. Please delete it.

Comment: aaarg :P +1 ^_^ This was my question ... :)

Comment: I was 20 sec quicker ;-) lol