# Apache2 syntax error AH00526 - while creating forward proxy vhost file

Tags: command-line, server, apache2, proxy, docker

I am making a proxy server using docker as done in this tutorial.
When I try and reload apache I get this error on line 4 and I'm not sure what it is from. Here is a copy of my vhost file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
ServerName my.server.name
<Proxy *>
Allow from localhost
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is a photo of my error.
[image]

I have also tried putting quotes around the asterisk on line 4 (as seen in apache documentation) `<Proxy "*">`

Can someone help show me my syntax error or explain to me what I am doing wrong here? I've been at this for 2 days.

Here is the tutorial I have been following: https://medium.com/@jmarhee/running-multiple-web-applications-on-a-docker-host-with-apache-85f673f02803

I found this question which seemed similar but not really what I needed.

[Unable to start Apache2 with Error AH00526: Syntax error - Invalid command $](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615498/unable-to-start-apache2-with-error-ah00526-syntax-error-invalid-command)

Comment: Try to enable the proxy: `sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http` and restart Apache.

Comment: Thank you so very much that worked. If you want to make that an answer I can mark it as the answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the Apache2 proxy modules are not enabled. Try to enable the two basic proxy modules and restart the server:

```bsh
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http           # Press [Tab] to find more modules
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

To find the enabled modules you could use:

```
sudo apache2ctl -M
```