# How do I enable ethernet, after a failed server dist upgrade to 14.04LTS?

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, ethernet, atheros

I did a server dist-upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04LTS, and in the process, lost all networking.  I'm open to either getting the existing drivers loaded and working, or seeing if a dist-upgrade to 16.04 (possible from DVD?) would fix things.  More interested in getting my ethernet working, but including wifi for completeness.

I've tried a bunch of suggestions, but right now, both eth0 and wlan0, after an `lshw` report `sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu... *-network UNCLAIMED`

My ether is Qualcom Atheros - AR8132 Fast Ethernet

My wifi is Broadcom - BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY

In /lib/firmware/br* there are a bunch of bin files, but there's no /lib/firmware/ar8* directory, but there are a bunch of other 'ar#' directories.

Definitely a noob with this, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Here are the added `lshw` results:

`*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:feafc000-feafffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: AR8132 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: c0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:febc0000-febfffff ioport:ec80(size=128)`

uname -a gives:

`Linux ubuntu 3.13.0.113-generic #160-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 9 09:28:25 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: it appears that you are missing the correct drivers for both cards. did you install them yourself? you may need to reinstall for the new kernel

Comment: I didn't.  That is, I typed in `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and everything seemed fine, until I realized there was no networking of any sort.  I'm sure it's drivers, but I keep finding suggestions that involve downloading and installing new ones, but... no networking. ;)

Comment: Have you tried 'sudo services network-manager restart'?

Comment: Well, that can't be good...  `sudo: services: command not found`

Comment: I'd start with https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into, and add outputs of `lshw -C network` and `dmesg | grep eth0` to the question. As is, there is no info to diagnose the problem, which makes the question rather vague. Also, `dist-upgrade` is a command that doesn't upgrade to a new release. Are you sure you've used that command, and it got you from 12.04 to 14.04?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `do-release-upgrade`.  The `dmesg...` didn't do anything, returning instantly to the prompt.  Will add the `lshw` to the question.

Comment: `linux-image-extra` is not installed.  It is unclear which kernel is installed now, so don't ask me for step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get the `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-113-generic_3.13.0-113.160_i386.deb` on its own, or any of the many drivers suggested in other threads, but by going to https://ubuntuupdates.org, and backtracking through the errors of what was missing, I searched the missing items, and kept trying installs, until one finally went through without errors.  With `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`, I installed in this order, which might vary for you, or you may require additional/fewer installs, and may not make any sense to the more experienced, but worked for me:

`linux-headers-3.13.0-129_3.13.0-129.178_all.deb`
`linux-headers-3.13.0-129-generic_3.13.0-129.178_i386.deb`
`linux-headers-generic_3.13.0.129.138_i386.deb`

rebooted and saw it listed that "limited" (???) networking was back.  I tried, and was able to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` which took just under a full hour, had to fix a lot of config's and settings with PHP and apache, after manually re-installing them, because they were held back in the update/upgrade, but I'm back up in a basic capacity now.

Thanks for all of the patience and leads.  Hope this helps someone else.

P.S.  While I went from 12.04 to 14.04, because of a change with PHP, this post was helpful in getting apache back up, even though it addresses 13.10:   [Upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 - Apache not able to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368515/upgraded-to-ubuntu-13-10-apache-not-able-to-start)

Answer (score 1):

Install this package

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-113-generic_3.13.0-113.160_i386.deb

Most likely it is not installed. It contains almost all hardware drivers.

You may also need to install

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-generic-3.13.0-113-generic_3.13.0-113.160_i386.deb

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.13.0-113-generic_3.13.0-113.160_i386.deb

Comment: Unfortunately, that gave me `Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.13.0-113-generic cannot be found.`, which I've been trying to fix with the help of https://askubuntu.com/questions/334136/how-do-i-install-build-essential-without-an-internet-connection but that gives me a list of dead links.

Comment: the headers have to be installed first. https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-headers-generic

Comment: Install headers http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-generic-3.13.0-113-generic_3.13.0-113.160_i386.deb

Comment: @ravery - I got back: 
`Preparing to unpack linux-headers-generic_3.13.0.129.138_i386.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (3.13.0.129.138) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-3.13.0-129-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-3.13.0-129-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encounter while processing:
 linux-headers-generic`

Comment: @Pilot6 - I got back: `Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-113-generic (3.13.0-113.160) over (3.13.0-113.160) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.13.0-113-generic (3.13.0-113.160) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_post.d/dkms 3.13.0-113-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-113-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.13.0-113-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.13.0-113-generic-package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located`

Comment: So install `linux-headers` http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.13.0-113-generic_3.13.0-113.160_i386.deb

Comment: @Pilot6 - I got the same again.  `Please install the linux-headers-3.13.0-113-generic package.`  Which is what I thought I was trying to install.

Comment: There are two different packages `linux-headers` and `linux-headers-generic`. So install the other one. Or install both by one command.

Comment: I installed `linux-headers-3.13.0-113_3.13.0-113.160_all.deb` without issue.  From there, I tried to install: `linux-headers-generic_3.13.0.129.138_i386.deb` and `linux-headers-3.13.0-113-generic_3.13.0-113.160_i386.deb` which both failed, unable to find headers-generic.

Comment: `linux-headers-generic_3.13.0.129.138_i386.deb` is a wrong one.

Comment: I suggest to re-install. It is too hard for a newbie.

Comment: The problem is, that it's an upgrade of an existing server, and I don't want to lose all the my data, and a re-install, prompts me to repartition, etc.

Comment: P.S.  This is a dead link: `http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-generic-3.13.0-113-generic_3.13.0-113.160_i386.deb`